# CAPI does not support Password Based Encryption (PBE) encryption?

Tags: c++, cryptoapi, pbkdf2

I am trying to port a UNIX code using OpenSSL (PKCS#5 & PKCS#7) to windows.

In the case of OpenSSL, all the encoding/decoding (certificates or
passwords) is done transparently to the caller in the function
[CMS_Encrypt](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/CMS_encrypt.html), as it should be.

CAPI does the same thing in the case of
certificate based encryption inside the function [CryptEncryptMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
(no ASN details are revealed to the caller). After some googling, I found out the following [key generation implementation](http://www.idrix.fr/Root/content/view/37/54/). Now how am I supposed to use it in CAPI ?

Because CAPI does not
support PBE encryption at the high level (PBKDF2) my guess
is that the encoding has to be done (somehow?) manually. And by manually I mean writing
(and reading) the binary representations of various ASN tags. How am I supposed to do this ?

I cannot access the [msasn1.h](http://www.koders.com/c/fid4F23D8E46AFA71338959D003DFF969831DE6120C.aspx) API since msasn1.lib is never distributed. Has anyone been able to use CAPI interface for doing anything else other than certificates based encryption ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Are you trying to do PBE using an interface that doesn't support it, or are you asking how to generate a certificate and use CBE?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to do PBE using Microsoft CAPI interchangeably with OpenSSL, I believe.

Comment: A lot of applications are using OpenSSL in MS Windows. Why not just to use them?

Comment: Are you looking for this function? `BCryptDeriveKeyPBKDF2`,  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd433795.aspx